# Implication of wronskian $=0$. Mistake in the question?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I found this problem in Braun's Differential Equations book:

> Suppose that $W[y_1,y_2](t^*) = 0$ (this notation means wronskian of $y_1$ and $y_2$) and in addition $y_1(t^*) = 0$. Prove that either $y_1(t) \equiv 0 $  or $y_2(t) = \frac{y_2'(t^*)}{y_1'(t^*)}y_1(t)$.

However if $y_1(t) = t^2$ and $y_2(t) = e^t$ then 
$$ W[y_1,y_2] = t^2e^t-2te^t $$
so $W[y_1,y_2](0) = 0$ but the condition of the problem is never met.Is there a mistake in the problem? I am not sure if the problem was intented to assume that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions of a second order ODE. In that case, still I can't understand why $y_1(t^*)$ is not zero (in order to get the second result).

Comment: Are there any conditions given for the functions $y_1,y_2$?

Comment: I think the intention is to have $y_1, y_2$ be solutions of the ODE $y'' + p(x) y' + q(x)y = 0$. If $y_1(t^*) = y_1'(t^*)=0$, then $y_1(t) = 0$ for all $t$ by the uniqueness theorem (since 0 is another solution satisfying the initial conditions $y(t^*) = y'(t^*)=0$).

Comment: Hmm it is possible a typo then. For all questions before this one in the book, there is a note that "assume $y_1$ $y_2$ are solutions of the ODE"  you mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is rather an extended comment.

No, there are no typos in the problem.  Let $y_1, y_2$ be solutions of $y'' + p(x) y' + q(x) y = 0$, where $p, q \colon (\alpha, \beta) \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous.  Assume that, for some $t^* \in (\alpha, \beta)$, $W[y_1, y_2](t^*) = 0$ and $y_1(t^*) = 0$.  $(y_1, y_2)$ are linearly independent then. Suppose that $y_1 \not\equiv 0$.  Then, first, $y'_1(t^*) \ne 0$ (since otherwise that would contradict uniqueness), and, second, there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y_2(t) = c y_1(t)$, consequently $y'_2(t) = c y'_1(t)$,  for all $t \in (\alpha, \beta)$.  In particular,
\begin{equation*}
c = \frac{y'_2(t^*)}{y'_1(t^*)}.
\end{equation*}